# Modeling data for retrieving user by name in Cassandra

Tags: database-design, cassandra

I am working with a project using Cassandra for main database with "users" table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    address text,
    email text,
    password text,
    website text
)
```

My application needs to perform query list all users order by name with pagination and I'm struggling to design table to meet this requirement.

So what is the good way to design "users_order_by_name" for this case?

Thanks.

Updated: 
My question is about design table to get sorted query, the pagination part is not my concern.

I understand clustering keys can be used to get sorted results within a partition. But if I use "name" as clustering key. What should I use as partition key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagination is implemented on driver level, most drivers support it.

About sorting - there's a problem to implement it on the "table". You can use clustering key, so all the data will be sorted by this key on the partition level (id in your example).

So you have to sort partitions somehow, for example make first letter of name partition key, or make all this sorting on client side.

Comment: I thought about use first letter as partition key already. But I think it will cause data to be spread unevenly. Which is bad according to http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling.

Comment: Sure. But you trying to do with Cassandra something it wasn't built to - full table sort. If you can partition your data by something else (based on your  queries), do it, and add name as clustering key.

Comment: @Yoshi upvoted. Making the first letter of the username the partition key and the username the clustering key will probably save the day. If you have a lot of users whose name begins with the same letter, chose the first two letters, or another "candidate", such as the suffix of the email address of the user (eg ".com", ".it", etc...), or something like that, but in that case you'd lose the "native" ordering because you'd need to sort on client side once you have all the results.

Comment: @xmas79 using first several letters is the best solution I have now

Comment: @Yoshi indeed this model will keep the order of the users even across the multiple queries you'll have to do to query all the partitions.

Comment: @xmas79 Thank you for reminding me. I figured out a way to query it without query all partitions already.

Comment: @Yoshi how? Can you share the solution? Thanks.

Comment: I'll gladly share my idea. It is a bit complicated to share in a comment. Can you give me your email so I can write it up and send you later. Or are there any better way?

Comment: @Yoshi it seems to me that the best fit is to post it as an answer, because it is an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

1. What programming language do you use? You can rely on built-in drivers pagination (see [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/paging/) for example).
2. You can use on-the-disk sorting [provided by clustering key](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refClstrOrdr.html), see also [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order). 
   So you can just add `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (name)` at the create table DDL.
   if you want to use partition key, then it should be considered too.

Comment: I use golang, but my problem here is language agnostic, it's more about table design. I know I can order by clustering key. But it means I have to store all my users into 1 partition, and I think it is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Just adding the the name as a clustering key is not sufficient. A query can only produce sorted results per partition key. So retrieving all users sorted by name won't work if `id` is the partition key.

Comment: The question about language meant that drivers support pagination. However, I have no experience with Golang. As for partitioning, how many users will you have? @Ralf, I supposed we could use single partition.

Comment: Partitions could be defined naturally if we have more information about use cases. Suppose, we always want to get not all users, but the subset of users related to some website. So, we could add partition by website.

Comment: My problem is sorted results and not about pagination. My number of users would grow in the future. So I don't think store all users in one partition is good idea.

Comment: Sadly the use case is list users by name sorted by alphabetical order. I don't see any appropriate partition key yet. I'm thinking about using first letter in name as partition key. But it seems like anti-pattern too, because it will spread data unevenly.

Comment: You could have make `name` the partition key and use the Byte Order Partitioner. But using this partitioner is highly [discouraged](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order). If you have a small enough number of users to make the "list all" use case useful, then you can go single partition as @S.Stas suggests. If you have that many users that you require distribution, then the "list all" use case is not really viable, I'd say.

Comment: My use case is list with pagination, so it is not actually all data and the return set is small for each page.

Comment: But what is a user supposed to do with a list of the first 20 of 100'000 users? Irrespective of how you get to the 20 list entries, the chances that the list shows what the user needs is incredibly low.

Comment: From UI stand point you can imagine it is something like ios contact list with infinite scrolling. So first I will list first 20 entries then load more when come down. I will have search, but it should be another problem.